# Deleted source files by GitHub merge in NetBeams

Tags: git, github

Hello I have really strange problem.

I am really new to all this GitHub stuff and so I was trying some stuff.
Basically what happened is, I had a Project in Netbeams and wanted to post iton my GitHub. So I created repository on Github and wanted to add files to it.

So I went into Netbeams, and Initialized Git Repository.
After that I went into Git->Commit
Then I tried to Push all the stuff, so Remote->Push
Not knowing what could go wrong, I mindlessly clicked all the branching thing like there was something master->master or sometig like that, I really dont know now.

But the thing is, it failed. So I somehow tought it would be good idea to do a Pull,dont really know why. This is also where it went wrong. Clicked all the stuff and it the end, there was a window asking me if I want to Rebase/Merge. I clicked Rebase. Then another window popped telling me something about checkout conflict, so I clicked Revert and all the sudden my files are gone.

I managed to recreate this. Basically it happens when I have a project and I Pull from my empty project at GitHub. Is there any way to get my files back?

EDIT: Output from console

```
4b83b06 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: pull --no-rebase --progress origin: Fast-forward
    d47acf2 HEAD@{1}: 
    4b83b06 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{2}: commit: Wa
    d47acf2 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from HEAD to master
    d47acf2 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to origin/master
    d47acf2 HEAD@{5}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
    d47acf2 HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from master to d47acf26594fc3d07b7709ff38a56284267ab993
    330a8a3 HEAD@{7}: commit (initial):
```

Git staus:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   nbproject/private/private.xml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        nbproject/project.properties

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

The chceckout message:

```
$ git checkout 330a8a3
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        nbproject/private/private.xml
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        nbproject/project.properties
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Comment: Open a terminal, and type `git reflog`. Then `git checkout` the hash of the previous commit before the rebase.

Comment: Is it somehow possible on windows?

Comment: Git runs on Windows, so all of its commands also run on Windows. I'd recomment `git-bash` on Windows.

Comment: Okay, downloaded GitBash, so now I did git reflog and it showed me bunch of stuff, bu what should I exactly do now?

Comment: I have his if it helps:  d47acf2 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from HEAD to master
d47acf2 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to origin/master
d47acf2 HEAD@{5}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
d47acf2 HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from master to d47acf26594fc3d07b7709ff38a562                 84267ab993
330a8a3 HEAD@{7}: commit (initial):

Comment: Please edit that output into your question. It's really hard to read with the newlines stripped out.

Comment: You want the commit you were on *immediately before you started the rebase*, which is not shown in the output you are showing.

Comment: Oooh wait a second, there is one more there, I am so sorry, hope thats the right one, will edit immediately

Comment: I have to confess I'm a bit confused. This looks a little bit like you're halfway through a pull. Can you also provide the output of `git status`?

Comment: Assuming your initial commit contains your files (that is, they weren't just hanging out in your working directory), you should be able to restore with `git checkout 330a8a3`.

Comment: Well, its kinda not working, dont know why, cannot it be because of like  thnk two branches there? master and origin/master? But dont know what do they do...

Comment: If you were able to reproduce the problem entirely on the command line, it would make easier to see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you @merlin2011 for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your files back, they have to have been part of the "commit" before you performed the rebase.
To fix the message you got when you tried to checkout that first commit:

```
$ git checkout 330a8a3
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
nbproject/private/private.xml
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
nbproject/project.properties
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

You need to stash your working tree changes. git is stopping you from checking out the previous commit because the file `nbproject/private/private.xml` has been changed in your working tree, and checking out that commit would lose the recent changes. You should run `git stash`, which will save your current working tree files. You can then run that checkout command again, `git checkout 330a8a3` which should complete without errors. Now you should be able to see your original files (at least all of the files that you "commit"ed to the repository.

At this point, I would copy the wanted files elsewhere for safekeeping. If you want to keep the changes that you had made in that `private.xml` file, run the following:

`git checkout master
git stash apply`

This will let you view the most recent commit on `master`, and then "load" your changes that you saved earlier using `git stash`.

Comment: I LOVE YOU!!! I had to delete some files from there, but they were not important anyway and I GOT them back!!! Thank you SO much for this. What I did was remove every file, like private.xml and others and then did git chceckout 330a8a3 and it worked!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, for marking my answer as the solution, and I am glad your problem is fixed! I suggest you read the documentation on the `stash` command, as it is absolutely vital when using `git`. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash